# How to setup RSpec in Eclipse?

Tags: ruby, eclipse

I have installed DLTK plugin to my Eclipse, so that I can program Ruby in Eclipse. Then I have installed RSpec. When I try to Run As Ruby Test, I always get the following errors:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /Users/apple/Downloads/eclipse4ruby/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/300/1/.cp/testing/dltk-rspec-runner.rb:12:in `rescue in <main>'
from /Users/apple/Downloads/eclipse4ruby/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/300/1/.cp/testing/dltk-rspec-runner.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Dose any additional setup/configuration need on Eclipse to support RSpec?

Comment: The problem is that DLTK only supports up to RSpec 1: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=325971

Answer (score -1):

The error message says that the spec gem cannot be found.
Try:

```
sudo gem install spec
```

Comment: Definitely not this -- the `spec` gem is unrelated to RSpec: https://rubygems.org/gems/spec